# Tables side by side with overflow

Tags: html, html-table

I want a 6 tables side by side, but when they reach the end of they are ordered at the next line.

I tried float but the elements still started at the next line when the display width were achieved.

Any tips are welcome.

Here is my code: I took away all style formats because I couldn't line them up in one line.

```
Link: http://jsfiddle.net/S3n6D/101/
```

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: Yeah I just took away the style cause I really messed it up... Can you give me hints?

Comment: You should paste the actual code into the question using a code snippet rather than have a link.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use this css;

```
table {
    width:15%;
    float:left;
}
```

you could also alter the body width if you want a wider table;

```
body {
    width:1800px;
}

table {
    width:300px; /* or 15% if you want it more dynamic */
    margin:0;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: When the end of line is reached the elements are set on a new line... I just want to line them up and make it scrollable...

Answer (score 0):

After some Clean and Order into your code, please try it:

```css
div {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="1">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Filiale</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
<br>
<div>
  <table border="1">
    <!-- MO -->
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="14">19.09.2016</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>5</th>
        <th>6</th>
        <th>7</th>
        <th>8</th>
        <th>9</th>
        <th>10</th>
        <th>11</th>
        <th>12</th>
        <th>13</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>


<div>
  <table border="1">
    <!-- DI -->
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="13">20.09.2016</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>5</th>
        <th>6</th>
        <th>7</th>
        <th>8</th>
        <th>9</th>
        <th>10</th>
        <th>11</th>
        <th>12</th>
        <th>13</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div>
  <table border="1">
    <!-- MI -->
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="13">21.09.2016</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>5</th>
        <th>6</th>
        <th>7</th>
        <th>8</th>
        <th>9</th>
        <th>10</th>
        <th>11</th>
        <th>12</th>
        <th>13</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div>
  <table border="1">
    <!-- DO -->
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="13">22.09.2016</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>5</th>
        <th>6</th>
        <th>7</th>
        <th>8</th>
        <th>9</th>
        <th>10</th>
        <th>11</th>
        <th>12</th>
        <th>13</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div>
  <table border="1">
    <!-- FR -->
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="13">23.09.2016</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>5</th>
        <th>6</th>
        <th>7</th>
        <th>8</th>
        <th>9</th>
        <th>10</th>
        <th>11</th>
        <th>12</th>
        <th>13</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div>
  <table border="1">
    <!-- SA -->
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th rowspan="1">&nbsp;</th>
        <th colspan="13">24.09.2016</th>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>5</th>
        <th>6</th>
        <th>7</th>
        <th>8</th>
        <th>9</th>
        <th>10</th>
        <th>11</th>
        <th>12</th>
        <th>13</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. But I wanna line them up and without line break... Overflow should be scrolled... I'm a very beginner and tried so much...